# button:focus work perfectly on chrome but not on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, button, focus, mozilla

I have a button and I want to make some styling on focus on that button.
On chrome works perfectly, on Firefox nothing happen.

```
<button class="cButton">
    button
</button>
```

```
.cButton {
color: black;
background: green;
}
.cButton:focus {
    color: white;
    background: red;
}
```

I've tried

```
.cButton::-moz-focus-inner {
    color: white;
    background: red;
}
```

and it didn't work.
I am using Firefox 63 on macOS.

Comment: how are you "focusing" on the button? According to MDN clicking a button in Firefox on OSX does NOT focus.

Comment: I'm focussing like that .cButton:focus

Comment: no how are you actually focusing on the button to test your CSS?

Comment: click and tab works on chrome but on firefox work only tab

Comment: Yes the answer below and my comment both are telling you "click" on Mac OS does NOT work to focus a button. It will never work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [Mozila developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Clicking_and_focus) website I found that button does not have focus state for Mac OS

[image]

Comment: Yeah i've tried that and on win10 works on every browser.